# How to define default null value in application.yml in Spring Boot

Tags: null, spring-boot, yaml, default-value, spring-el

I'm trying to define the default value as null value in application.yml with SpringBoot version 1.3.0.RELEASE. The goal is be able to refer it with a class with `ConfigurationProperties` annotation

```
-- application.yml --
test.foo: ${test.bar:#{null}}
```

but it doesn't work.

If the value of `test.bar` is not defined, set `test.foo` to null (default value)

I already have spring-el in my dependencies. I don't want to use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setNullValue`

It's seem to work in `@Value` but not in `application.yml` (see http://farenda.com/spring/spring-inject-null-value/)

It's a bug, or yaml is not designed for that?
I tried all values in http://yaml.org/type/null.html but it doesn't worked either

Thanks

Comment: We don't apply SpEL expression in configuration files as [explained in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties)

Comment: Thanks, if I understand, the only way is using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setNullValue` ?

Answer (score 8):

#### @Value

From the document, we can see:

> A common use case is to assign default field values using "#{systemProperties.myProp}" style expressions.

It is actually three phases here:

- Spring get the annotation string -- `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`
- Spring get property value by the annotation meta data -- `Environmen`
- Spring interpret the property value -- `ExpressionParser`

#### User Case

If we define a `test.foo` in `application.yml` like you have described:

```
-- application.yml --
test.foo: ${test.bar:#{null}}
```

Then, we refer to it in code via `@Value`, it works as you said.

```
@Autowired
public A(@Value("test.foo") Object a) {}
```

But If we get it directly from `environment`, it will be plain string:

```
env.getProperty("test.foo")
```

#### More

So, whether it is work or not depends on how did you use it. I can't provide more help before more info. Hope following related post may help.

- [Spring EL tutorial](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/10/learn-spring-expression-language.html)
- [Spring Boot: customize environment](http://tonyz93.blogspot.com/2017/09/spring-boot-customize-environment.html)

Comment: Hi, thank you but it doesn't help much. What infos do you need? I yould like to define default null value in application.yml (with spring boot out of box). "If the value of test.bar is not defined, set test.foo to null (default value)"

Comment: @khong07 I mean how do you refer your `test.foo`. If you refer it using `@Value`, it works.

Comment: i refer it with a class with `ConfigurationProperties` annotation ;)

Answer (score 3):

you need to set it like that:

```
test:
  foo: ${test.bar:#{null}}
```

**Edit:** The answer showed `${test.bar:'#{null}'}` before, which is not correct.

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: This worked when I removed the single quotes. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
-- application.yml --
test.foo: ${test.bar:}
```

Comment: Just tried this, but this results in the empty string "".