# How to return a null value from config server in PCF?

Tags: pcf, configserver

I am trying to receive a null value from the Config Server in a microservice. I have tried "null" (without quotes) as well as "${null}" (also without quotes) in the application.yml the config server is referencing. Both served an empty string. Is there any way to return a null? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A bit more context would be helpful. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to (A) omit the URL of the config server within the application.yml, or (B) do you want the config server to return a null value for a specific property of an app in a specific environment? I would guess you are trying to do (B). Have you tried not specifying the property at all? Why do you need a null value as opposed to an empty string?

Comment: I am authenticating a bearer token in Zuul, and the token specifies the target ResourceId. The library I am using recognizes null config values and does not validate against it if it is null - thus I need the config server to server me a null value.

Comment: I just @Override the method in the library and served the configuration a null value. Not ideal, but I worked around it.

Answer (score 0):

There is already [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041197/how-to-define-default-null-value-in-application-yml-in-spring-boot) open for the same problem. and there is no concrete answer available.

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway.